# Survival Analysis with "Drop Out" and "Drop In"?

Tags: r, regression, survival, panel-data

Using the R programming language, I created the following dataset to simulate a medical study in which patients were :

- Given a Treatment or a Placebo
- Had their weights recorded over a period of time
- Recorded if some "Event" had occurred or not as of the last time they were measured

  ```
   id = 1:100
    weight_time_1 = abs(rnorm(100,180,10))
    weight_time_2 = abs(rnorm(100,180,10))
    weight_time_3 = abs(rnorm(100,180,10))
    weight_time_4 = abs(rnorm(100,180,10))
    weight_time_5 = abs(rnorm(100,180,10))
    weight_time_6 = abs(rnorm(100,180,10))

    response <- c("censor","event")

    response_at_last_non_NA_measurement <- sample(response, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7))

    class <- c("placebo","treatment")

    cohort <- sample(class, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7))

    my_data = data.frame(id = 1:100,
                         d1 = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 100),
                         d2 = as.Date(NA),
                         d3 = as.Date(NA),
                         d4 = as.Date(NA),
                         d5 = as.Date(NA), d6 = as.Date(NA)
    )

    for(i in 1:nrow(my_data)){
      for(j in 2:6){
        prev <- my_data[i, j]
        my_data[i, j+1] <- sample(seq(as.Date(prev), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 1)
      }
    }

    my_data = cbind(cohort, my_data, weight_time_1, weight_time_2, weight_time_3, weight_time_4, weight_time_5, weight_time_6, response_at_last_non_NA_measurement)

    library(data.table)

    setDT(my_data)

    my_data[sample(.N, 25), c('weight_time_1', 'd1'):=NA]
    my_data[sample(.N, 25), c('weight_time_2', 'd2'):=NA]
    my_data[sample(.N, 25), c('weight_time_3', 'd3'):=NA]
    my_data[sample(.N, 25), c('weight_time_4', 'd4'):=NA]
    my_data[sample(.N, 25), c('weight_time_5', 'd5'):=NA]
    my_data[sample(.N, 25), c('weight_time_6', 'd6'):=NA]


    my_data = data.frame(my_data)
  ```

In the end, the data looks something like this:

```
     cohort id         d1         d2         d3         d4         d5         d6 weight_time_1 weight_time_2 weight_time_3 weight_time_4 weight_time_5 weight_time_6 response_at_last_non_NA_measurement
1 treatment  1       <NA> 2011-10-19 2015-10-24       <NA> 2019-08-31 2019-09-20            NA      180.1905      181.7374            NA      204.7340      158.7246                               event
2 treatment  2 2005-10-31 2014-10-29 2016-07-18       <NA> 2018-03-28 2018-12-08      180.2389      193.5359      188.5670            NA      178.8546      164.7420                              censor
3 treatment  3       <NA> 2017-10-19 2019-12-30 2019-12-31 2019-12-31       <NA>            NA      175.5434      174.9120      180.1217      169.9194            NA                              censor
4 treatment  4 2015-04-10       <NA> 2019-01-13 2019-07-27 2019-10-27 2019-11-16      191.4939            NA      162.2972      166.4303      182.6016      166.5155                              censor
5   placebo  5 2001-10-15       <NA> 2019-08-04 2019-12-09       <NA> 2019-12-29      165.8684            NA      171.8849      183.4390            NA      192.1001                               event
6   placebo  6 2009-01-15       <NA>       <NA> 2017-06-17 2018-11-08 2019-12-29      183.5914            NA            NA      171.3756      180.6863      171.9975                              censor
```

In most examples of Survival Analysis/Longitudinal Analysis that I read online, "Censoring" usually occurs in the form of "patient dropout" - mainly, once a patient is censored, the patient is usually considered absent for the remainder of the medical study. The other forms of censoring I usually come across are patients who have not experienced the "event" at the time the study is completed, or patients that experience the "event" between measurements.

In this example that I have created above, patients are now allowed to "drop out" and "drop back in" throughout the medical study - this means that some patients will inevitably be measured more frequently than some patients, along with regular censoring phenomena.

**In such cases, do "special types" of Survival/Longitudinal models need to be implemented and adapted to accommodate for this kind of behavior - or can standard Survival/Longitudinal models still be used?**

Thanks!

Comment: There is no need for special survival methods, provided some standard assumptions about the censoring process are met. However, you will need to transform your dataset into a `(start, stop]` format, to tell the model when an individual is under observation and when they're not. See the [time dependent vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) for an example of that (pg 4).

Comment: What you describe as "drop in/drop out" seems to be [tag:missing-data] in a time series setting (some dates are observed, some are not).

Comment: Do you want to incorporate `weight` as a time-varying predictor of outcome? Are patients known to be on either `Treatment` or `Placebo` even when they haven't been seen at follow-up for a while?